# Can't run this C code: no errors or warnings but the program just crashes

Tags: c, warnings

I'm not complaining anything about the code results but, when I run the code, the IDE immediately stops working.

I tried many IDEs and editors and still doesn't do anything and there is no error or warning.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NUM_STRING 4
#define MAX_STRING_SIZE 40

char* getWord()
{
    static char words[NUM_STRING][MAX_STRING_SIZE] = {
        "game",
        "hello",
        "program",
        "pointer"
    };
    int randomIndex = rand() % 4;
    char* selectedWord = words[randomIndex];
    return selectedWord;
}

char GuessLetter()
{
    char letter;
    int value=1;

    while(value)
    {
        printf("\nmake a guess: ");
        if(scanf("%c", &letter) != 1)
        {
            printf("Please re-enter a letter");
        }
        else
        {
            value = 0;
        }
    }
return letter;
}

int checkchar(char* PW)
{
    int i, len = strlen(PW);
    for(i=0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if(PW[i]=='_')
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
return 0;
}
char* printafter( char *currentWord, int len, char letter, char *PW)
{
    int i;

    for(i=0; i<len; i++)
    {
        if(letter == currentWord[i])
        {
            PW[i] = letter;
        }
        printf("%c ", PW[i]);
    }
return PW;
}

void startGame()
{
    char* currentWord = getWord();
    char *PartialWord=NULL;
    int i, length = strlen(currentWord);

    printf("%s\n", currentWord);
    for(i=0; i<length; i++)
    {
        PartialWord[i] = '_';
        printf("_ ");
    }

    if(!(PartialWord = (char*)malloc(length)))
       {
           printf("Sorry there was an allocation error! ");
           exit(1);
       }

    while(checkchar(PartialWord))
    {
        PartialWord = printafter(currentWord, length, GuessLetter(), PartialWord);
    }
}
int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    startGame();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Its not crashing , it shows a word and ends

Answer (score 2):

The main problem in your code is that you are trying to assign data to the `PartialWord` array before you have allocated it! This causes **undefined behaviour** and almost *anything* can happen - including a partial output of the data, followed by a program crash.

Just move the `malloc` code to **before** the `for` loop in the `startGame` function (as shown below) ... and remember to `free()` the memory when you've finished with it:

```c
void startGame()
{
    char* currentWord = getWord();
    char* PartialWord = NULL;
    int i, length = strlen(currentWord);

    // You MUST have this allocation BEFORE you assign the '_' characters in the for loop!
    if (!(PartialWord = malloc(length))) { // Also, yoi don't need to (and shouldn't) cast the malloc return
        printf("Sorry there was an allocation error! ");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("%s\n", currentWord);
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        PartialWord[i] = '_'; // In your code, PartialWord is NULL when you do this!
        printf("_ ");
    }

    while (checkchar(PartialWord)) {
        PartialWord = printafter(currentWord, length, GuessLetter(), PartialWord);
    }

    free(PartialWord); // Remember to free the memory when you're done with it!
}
```

On the issue of whether or not to cast the result of `malloc`, see here: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/10871073).

Feel free to ask for any further clarification and/or explanation.